# Resolving Observables on properties of an Observable element

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

If I have list of items coming in Observable from an api, let's call them *list of "bars"*.

And now, for every `bar` I need to fetch a list of items related - let's call them "foo"s. Here's the thing - the api lets you retrieve list of `foo`s only when associated `bar`'s id provided.

So how do I do that? Should I fire a separate request in `subscribe | forEach`? or maybe I could create stream of urls and somehow merge them with stream of `bars` and do it that way?

You can create wonders using Rx when applied to UI stuff, unfortunately I'm having difficult time using it to work with multiple ajax requests.

Can you show me an example when you have one Observable and for every item you retrieve more data?

for example, if I try doing something like this:

```
Rx.Observable.fromArray([ { bar:1 }, { bar:2 }, { bar:3 } ])
.map((x)=> {
    x.foo = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(grabFoo(x));

    return x;
}).subscribe((x)=> console.log(x))
```

it wouldn't work. so how do I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this. I used flatMap.

Here is a redacted form of my working code:

*Updated with comments and using Bar and Foo and add listofbars()*

```
// accumulates all bar s and foo s
var data = {bars: [], errors: []};

// return observable of a foo
var getFoo = function (Id, apiKey) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: config.Uri + "/foos/" + Id,
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey },
    })).share();
};
// return Observable of an array of bars
var getBars = function (apiKey) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: config.Uri + "/bars",
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey },
    })).share();
};
// flatten Observable of an array of bar s to Observable of bar s
var listOfBars = function (apiKey) {
    return getBars(apiKey)
    .flatMap(function (ep) { return (_a = Rx.Observable).of.apply(_a, ep); var _a; });
}
// accumulate foos into data
var getDataForFoo = function (data, bar, apiKey) {
    return getFoo(bar.fooId, apiKey)
    .map(function (foo) {
        bar.foo = foo;
        data.bars.push(bar);
        return data;
    })
    .catch(function (ex) {
        data.errors.push({ name: { Id: Id, name: Name }, error: ex });
        return Rx.Observable.of(data);
    });
};
var getDataForBars = function (data, apiKey) {
    return listOfBars(apiKey)
    .flatMap(function (bar) { return getDataForFoo(data, bar, apiKey); })
    .catch(function (ex) {
        data.errors.push({ names: { Id: Id }, error: ex });
        return Rx.Observable.of(data);
    });
};
```

This flatMap takes arrays of bar and emits each bar separately.

```
    .flatMap(function (ep) { return (_a = Rx.Observable).of.apply(_a, ep); var _a; })
```

This flatMap takes each bar and makes a new web request using the fooId from the bar.

```
    .flatMap(function (bar) { return getDataForFoo(data, bar, apiKey); })
```

The above example accumulates the bar s and foo s into a data model. You appear to be asking for a stream of bar that contains the foo. Given the above that would look like:

```
var barswithfoo = listOfBars(apiKey)
    .flatMap(bar => { 
        return getFoo(bar.fooId, apiKey)
            .map(foo => {
                bar.foo = foo; 
                return bar;
            });
    })
    .subscribe();
```

You can see that this is similar to the answer you posted. flatMap is a map + merge. it expects the map to return an Observable and immediately subscribes to every observable that is returned.

Comment: can you explain what's happening here? `name`, `names`, `dataForName`, `dataForNames`. I'm a bit confused. What's the "entry point" here?

Comment: can you please tell me what is `share()` for why do you needed here?

Comment: Sure. Names is a set of bar objects from the question, while each name is a foo object. The entry point is getDataForNames, which returns an Observable that emits the data var every time it is changed (by adding a name or an error). I use this to update a redux store which then triggers a react component to render the set of names.

Comment: and on `of.apply` thing you totally lost me :(

Comment: share() is the same as publish().refCount()  this allows multiple subscriptions to share the result of one Ajax call.

Comment: this is really good, matured and detailed example. I will try to contemplate every piece of it. I have a feeling I will learn a lot from it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The of.apply was an expansion of the new 'spread' es6 syntax to es5. There are other ways to take an array and emit each item from a new observable.

Comment: My pleasure. I do not regret any of the time I spent learning Rx- have fun!

Comment: still can't find a way to apply this to my case. I've updated the question, added trivial sample of what I'm trying to do. Would you please take another look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, to actually make something like that work, I tried this first:

```
listOfbars.flatMap(x => 
     getFoo(x).then(r => {
         x.foo = r;
         return x; 
     })
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

it works, although it is painfully slow (because I assume it resolves all promises only in the end), compared to this:

```
listOfbars.flatMap(x => 
     Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getFoo(x))
     .map(r => { 
          x.foo = r; 
          return x; 
      })
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

It looks like the second snippet shouldn't even work, surpisingly it does

Comment: yes, the second is a good translation of my answer to just return each bar+foo instead of accumulating all the bars into a data object. I updated my answer to make this clearer.